# Is there an order in the interpretation of REST endpoints?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-rest

If you have multiple files with different endpoints such as

```
@RequestMapping(value="/identity" , method=RequestMethod.GET) 
@RequestMapping(value="/mobilities/validate" , method=RequestMethod.POST) 
@RequestMapping(value="/upload" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

And in another file(s)

```
@GetMapping("/*")
@GetMapping("/*/*")
```

*The files being `@Controller`*

If I HTTP GET `/identity` how do I know for sure that the endpoint that is going to be used is the `/identity` and not `/*` ?

Is there an order (as in NodeJS where `/*` before `/identify` would always do the `/*` function) or is it EXACT route then if none match, it goes back to the stars ?

Comment: The `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` will do a best effor to find the best matching request handling method (aka them ost specific one).

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm actually trying to see if it is safe to deliver the `index.html` of my React app all the time at the endpoint `/*`in case of refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it will try its best to match the inbound request.